# Excel SQL Syntax JET OleDB Reference?

Tags: sql, excel, oledb

I´m querying an Excel Sheet from a .NET Application with an Jet driver.

Are there any ressources on SQL on Excel files covering:

Formats, DataTypes, DataConversions, Supported Statements ... ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL syntax is the same as for the Access database engine (Jet, whatever) version 4.0 i.e. Access2000 through Access2003.

The way the driver/provider works out data types is a little odd and can be frustrating that you can't just specify what they should be (as you can e.g. for a text file using a schema.ini file). [This article I wrote on the subject](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/03/external-data-mixed-data-types/) many moons ago still gets a lot of traffic, read the comments for advanced help.

Comment: thank you, it´s a good starting point
Maybe i´m not finding something in the referance, but how can i cast strings to dates?

Comment: Found a solution for my question
in c# i use  CDate('<system.datetime.now>')
strange topic anyway.

Comment: @excelguy: it was merely linking to the top-level Access/Jet SQL in the Access2003 online reference i.e. not particularly useful anyhow so I've removed it.